# C++ tbb flow graph, multifunction_node giving incomplete type error

Tags: c++, tbb-flow-graph

Far as I understand, incomplete type error happens when there's forward declaration without full specification of type, then instantiate that type since the compiler can't tell the size of such type.
In my case I don't understand how this code produces such a problem. For simplicity I've removed unrelated parts.

```
class FilterOnNode {
   struct PartialResult { int n1,n2; long e; };
   typedef PartialResult* InputResult;
   typedef tbb::flow::multifunction_node<InputResult, InputResult> FilterNodeType;

   void BuildGraph(tbb::flow::graph &g, tbb::flow::graph_node &src) {
       auto sampleNode = FilterNodeType(
                g,
                tbb::flow::concurrency::unlimited,
                [&](const InputResult &input, typename FilterNodeType::output_ports_type &op) { //error points to here
                    //some logic here... might not send message.
                    std::get<0>(op).try_put(input);
                });
       tbb::flow::make_edge(src, sampleNode);
       //create couple other nodes like previous then connect edges
       tbb::flow::make_edge(tbb::flow::output_port<0>(sampleNode), otherNode);
   }
```

compiler is giving error of incomplete type at the lambda expression. Exact error says:

> `/usr/local/include/tbb/flow_graph.h:1568:7: error: incomplete type ‘std::tuple_size<FilterOnNode::PartialResult*>’ used in nested name specifier class multifunction_node`

Isn't the type PartialResult fully specified already? Tried taking it out of the class but still same problem.

Comment: I think you need a semi colon after the struct definition.

Comment: @M.A It exists in the code, got lost in copy-paste... editing question to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't the type PartialResult fully specified already?

Yes, but that is not what the error message complains about. The error message should be read as *"error: incomplete type ‘[**name of the incomplete type**]’ used [**place where it is used**]"*. The incomplete type is `std::tuple_size<FilterOnNode::PartialResult*>`, not `PartialResult`. There is no definition of `std::tuple_size<T>` when `T` is a pointer (e.g. `PartialResult*`).

The location of the use of the incomplete type has something to do with `class multifunction_node`. I looked around for the header defining this and found the following. (I don't know why this information was not in the API documentation that I found.)

**`tbb/flow_graph.h`, beginning of the definition of `multifunction_node`:**

> ```
> //! implements a function node that supports Input -> (set of outputs)
> // Output is a tuple of output types.
> template<typename Input, typename Output, typename Policy = queueing>
> class multifunction_node :
> ```

So the `Output` parameter has to be a tuple of output types, yet you supplied a raw output type. Try changing your definition of `FilterNodeType` to the following.

```
typedef tbb::flow::multifunction_node<InputResult, std::tuple<InputResult>> FilterNodeType;
//                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^           ^
```

It might be possible to replace `std::tuple` with `tbb::flow::tuple`, but I did not look into how the TBB tuple is to be used.

Comment: I see, seems like I was reading the error message in the wrong way at first place. Thanks for your explanation.